# Kommunicate producing IllegalArgumentException when logging in using release build but is working fine in debug build

Tags: android, kotlin, kommunicate

I am trying to integrate Kommunicate Chatbot in my Android App.
After I have created KMUser with UserId and trying to login using Kommunicate.login(), it is giving me IllegalArgumentException, in onFailure() function.

This exception only occurs in release build, but not in debug build.

I have tried switching data in KMUser but didn't help.

Here is the code snippet.

```
Kommunicate.init(this@HomeActivity, APP_ID)

        if (!(mHomeViewModel?.dbProfileResponseModel?.contactNum.isNullOrEmpty())) {
            kmUser.userId = mHomeViewModel?.dbProfileResponseModel?.contactNum
        } else {
            kmUser = Kommunicate.getVisitor()
        }
        if (!(mHomeViewModel?.dbProfileResponseModel?.email.isNullOrEmpty())) {
            kmUser.email = mHomeViewModel?.dbProfileResponseModel?.email
        }

        kmUser.applicationId = APP_ID
```

```
Kommunicate.login(this@HomeActivity, kmUser, object : KMLoginHandler {
            override fun onSuccess(registrationResponse: RegistrationResponse?, context: Context?) {

                val botIds = arrayListOf<String>()
                botIds.add("beekun-yx526")

                KmConversationBuilder(this@HomeActivity)
                        .setSingleConversation(false)
                        .setBotIds(botIds)
                        .setKmUser(kmUser)
                        .launchConversation(object : KmCallback {
                            override fun onSuccess(message: Any) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss()
                            }

                            override fun onFailure(error: Any) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss()
                            }
                        })

            }

            override fun onFailure(registrationResponse: RegistrationResponse?, exception: Exception?) {
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss()
                }
                createLoginErrorDialog(registrationResponse, exception)
            }
        })
```

This is the exception raised.

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class c.b.g.a declares multiple JSON fields named a
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.b.a.i.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.b.a.i.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.a(Gson.java:458)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.a(Gson.java:696)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.a(Gson.java:683)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.b(Gson.java:638)
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.b(Gson.java:618)
W/System.err:     at com.applozic.mobicomkit.api.a.a.a.a(RegisterUserClientService.java:100)
W/System.err:     at c.b.a.i.a(KmUserLoginTask.java:62)
W/System.err:     at c.b.a.i.doInBackground(KmUserLoginTask.java:24)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:334)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:246)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Please help me out resolving this issue.

Comment: Pls show your data class. I think issue is there in data class.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the issue with build flavor, you might have enabled proguard for release build and haven't added their proguard rules in your proguard-rules.pro file.

Checkout the doc to add the rules in your proguard file: https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/android-installation#building-with-proguard